# How to pass variable into xpath expression in protractor with Javascript

Tags: javascript, xpath, protractor

I have to fetch a value from calendar, then add one to it and then use the added value to the xpath to get the next date in calendar. Below is the sample where am stuck. Appreciate any help regarding this

```
element(by.xpath('//span[@class="ng-binding text-info"]')).getText().then(function (text) {
            var val = parseInt(text.value) + 1;
            console.log('Next Day Date is ' + parseInt(text.value) + 1);
               //How should i write val below? 
                element.by(by.xpath('//span[@text()='+"+val]'))
            });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fairly simple, but the combination of single and double quotes looks confusing at first glance:

```
element(by.xpath("//span[@text()='" + val + "']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:

```
var dt = new Date();
var current_day = (dt.getDate()).toString();

end_day = element.all(by.xpath("//span[text()='" + current_day + "']"));
```